# Why does the hamiltonian in the operator act on the wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, quantum-states

Suppose we have the following relation:

$H_0 | \phi_1\rangle  = E_1 |\phi_1 \rangle $

Why is it that if we take the unitary function $$U_{0} = \exp\left(\frac{-iH_{0}t}{\hbar}\right)$$

and apply it to the state $| \phi_1 \rangle$ we deduce that:

$$ U_{0} |\phi_1\rangle = \exp\left(\frac{-iE_1t}{\hbar}\right)| \phi_1\rangle. $$

In other words how can we say the operator $H_{0}$ operates even when it is in the exponential and is not seemingly acting directly on the state.

Comment: You can easily expand the exponential term, then use $H_{0}|\phi_{1}> = E_{1}|\phi_{1}>$ and iterate it, this whole sum will become the exponential with energy eigenvalue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make some sense of this, think of how we define the exponential of an operator. It is defined in terms of a Taylor Series, meaning
\begin{equation}
U_0\left|\phi_1\right> = \exp\left({\frac{-it}{\hbar}H_0}\right)\left|\phi_1\right> = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{-it}{\hbar}\right)^{n}H_0^n\left|\phi_1\right>
\end{equation}
Since $H_0\left|\phi_1\right> = E_1\left|\phi_1\right>$, we know
\begin{equation}
U_0\left|\phi_1\right> = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{-it}{\hbar}\right)^{n}E_1^n\left|\phi_1\right> = \exp\left({\frac{-it}{\hbar}E_1}\right)\left|\phi_1\right>
\end{equation}